# ListView items animation trouble

Tags: android, listview, animation

I remove a ListView item with slide up animation. Then the views below are slided up all together. Everything looks great except there is an empty space in the bottom.

Does anyone know how to make such an animation?

Or how to make a listview keep one more "offscreen" view so it is slided too instead of empty space.